# Creating specific time stamps for objects?

Tags: java, oop, time

I'm not trying to use the current time at all. Im aware of the calendar and date java utils but I'm not sure how to create my OWN timestamps not dependent on the current time. For instance each object would have an "arrival time" variable in hh:mm:ss format. But I have no clue how to do this. Do I have to create my own class?

Comment: Look towards the newer `java.time` API. The answer to your question will depend greatly on what you want to achieve. If you need to calculate the difference between the times or order them in some specific manner, then you might be better using the `java.time` API as that functionality already exists

Comment: _"Do I have to create my own class?"_  Yes, at the very least you'll need a custom factory class to generate and dispense your timestamps.  The actual timestamp objects, however, could be either a JDK-provided type like `LocalTime` or a class of your own creation, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not perfectly clear, but I would think you’re after something like this:

```
public class MyObject {

    private static final DateTimeFormatter ARRIVAL_TIME_FORMATTER
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    // Some instance variables
    private LocalTime arrivalTime;

    public MyObject(LocalTime arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime;
    }

    public String getFormattedArrivalTime() {
        return arrivalTime.format(ARRIVAL_TIME_FORMATTER);
    }

}
```

As has been said in the comments, use a `LocalTime` for the time of day. Don’t worry about format when storing the arrival time in your object. Only format it when you need to display it. `LocalTime.of` creates a `LocalTime` not related to the current time. There are overloaded versions that also take seconds.

So no, don’t create your own timestamp class. Use `LocalTime` (or depending on requirements some other class) from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Let’s see a brief example of using the above `MyObject` class:

```
    MyObject obj = new MyObject(LocalTime.of(23, 45));
    System.out.println("Object arrived at " + obj.getFormattedArrivalTime());
```

Output:

> Object arrived at 23:45:00

In the output (and there only) the time has been formatted to `hh:mm:ss` as you requested.

**Edit:** `LocalTime` has a precision of nanoseconds. Basil Bourque is correct in his comment that if you know that you don’t want to store any finer precision than whole seconds, it’s easy to truncate the incoming value:

```
    public MyObject(LocalTime arrivalTime) {
        this.arrivalTime = arrivalTime.truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS);
    }
```

On one hand I’d hesitate to throw information away like this, and time stamps tend to benefit from precision. On the other hand it may also be confusing if your object stores a fraction of second that no one ever sees. You will have to decide yourself.

**Links**

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Documentation of `LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)